# A question on function analysis and limits.

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

The question provides me with $f(1)=1$ and $f'(1)=2$. I'm required to find the value of the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt{f(x)} - 1}{\sqrt{x} - 1}$$
I cannot figure out how to apply the first principle of differentiation. The answer should be 2.

Comment: Have you already studied l'Hospital's Rule?

Comment: DonAntinio- Can't we find out what the function is by performing an integral over df/dx=2? Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: And: did you mean $\;f'(\color{red}1)=2\;$ ?

Comment: @Chandrahas Yes, but I think that it might be a typo and the OP actually meant $\;f'(1)=2\;$ ... Let's wait to see whether the OP will address these doubts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you meant $\;f'(1)=2\;$ and with l'Hospital:

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt{f(x)}-1}{\sqrt x-1}\stackrel{l'H}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}}}{\frac1{2\sqrt x}}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt x\,f'(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)}}=\frac{\sqrt1f'(1)}{\sqrt{f(1)}}=\frac21=2$$

Comment: learn't about l'Hospital now and then saw you solution, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt{f(x)} - 1}{\sqrt{x} - 1}=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt{f(x)} - 1}{x - 1}(\sqrt x+1)=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt{f(x)} - 1}{x - 1}\cdot\lim_{x\to 1}(\sqrt x+1)=2\left(\sqrt{f(x)}\right)'_{x=1}.$$

Then use the chain rule:
$$\left(\sqrt{f(x)}\right)'=\color{red}{\frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake.